# Sort nested comments after date in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to take first 4 comments ordered descending from all comments in this xml, (ordered by date_added):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="get7Comments.xsl"?>

<products>
<product id="1">
    <comment id="1">
        <username>admin1</username>
        <text>nice</text>
        <date_added>20.06.2005</date_added>
    </comment>
    <comment id="2">
        <username>admin2</username>
        <text>too nice</text>
        <date_added>11.05.2005</date_added>
    </comment>
</product>
<product id="2">
    <comment id="1">
        <username>admin1</username>
        <text>comment1</text>
        <date_added>19.05.2005</date_added>
    </comment>
    <comment id="2">
        <username>daniel</username>
        <text>comment2</text>
        <date_added>06.05.2005</date_added>
    </comment>
    <comment id="3">
        <username>another</username>
        <text>comment3</text>
        <date_added>15.05.2005</date_added>
    </comment>
</product>
</products>
```

Example of output for the last 4 comments that I want:

```
admin1 : nice : 20.06.2005
admin1 : comment1  : 19.05.2005
another : comment3 : 15.05.2005
admin2 : too nice : 11.05.2005
```

Works perfectly if I let them as a list of items -comments-, but not after I separate them under a new tag

```
<product id=""> comments </product>
```

I can't sort them all and take first 4. How it works if I dont't have the 'product' tag, I mean all coments have as the parent 'products' tag :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match ="products">
<xsl:for-each select="product[position() &lt; 8]">

    <xsl:sort select="normalize-space(substring(date_added,7,4))" order="descending" />
    <xsl:sort select="normalize-space(substring(date_added,4,2))" order="descending" />
    <xsl:sort select="normalize-space(substring(date_added,0,2))" order="descending" />
    <xsl:variable name="commID" select="@id" />

    <a href="index.php?p=comment&amp;id={$commID}">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(text,0,60)" />
    </a><br/>

</xsl:for-each>

 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.  Please edit your post and show the output you want to get from the input.  Also, in your input the first nested tag under `<products>` is also `<products>`... should it be `<product>` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but try using an `xsl:apply-templates` instead of an `xsl:for-each`.

Example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match ="products">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="product/comment">
            <xsl:sort select="concat(
                normalize-space(substring(date_added,7,4)),
                normalize-space(substring(date_added,4,2)),
                normalize-space(substring(date_added,1,2))
                )" data-type="number" order="descending" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>      
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="comment">
        <!--xsl:if used because it wasn't working on the predicate?-->
        <xsl:if test="4 >= position()">
            <a href="index.php?p=comment&amp;id={@id}">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(text,1,60)" />
            </a><br/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>                  
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>     

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

using your XML input produces:

```
<a href="index.php?p=comment&amp;id=1">nice</a><br>
<a href="index.php?p=comment&amp;id=1">comment1</a><br>
<a href="index.php?p=comment&amp;id=3">comment3</a><br>
<a href="index.php?p=comment&amp;id=2">too nice</a><br>
```

Your href's will need modifying if you have duplicate comment id's across products (like you have in your example XML).

***(Edit: Missed that you're trying to return the top 4 comments. Fixed. Also fixed typo in 3rd `substring()`.)***